# find special block at text ,with shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have to  get the special lines for a specific version (such as v2.0.1 or v2.0.2 and so on)

For example, for the input "v2.0.2", I want the the following output:

```
==2012-01-02 v2.0.2

some information about B..
```

Here is my textfile sample.txt:

```
==2012-01-01 v2.0.1

some information about A..

==2012-01-02 v2.0.2

some information about B..

==2012-01-03 v2.0.4

some information about C..
```

Comment: is your _special block_ of text always a single line and 2 lines below the version number line?

Comment: @ Édouard Lopez. The special block may contain several lines.may be one line ,may be two, may be three ,and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v s="$ver" 'BEGIN{gsub(/\./,"[.]",s)}$0~s{p=7;print;next}p&&/^==/{p=0}p' file
```

`$ver` is a shell var, containing the search string.

the `BEGIN{}` block is for escaping the `. (dot)`, since later we would use it as dynamic regexp.

Comment: Kent,thank you! But i can not get anything output...

david@workstation:~$ cat sample.txt 
==2012-01-01 v2.0.1

some information about A..

==2012-01-02 v2.0.2

some information about B..

==2012-01-03 v2.0.4

some information about C..
david@workstation:~$ 
david@workstation:~$ 
david@workstation:~$ ver=2.0.2
david@workstation:~$ 
david@workstation:~$ 
david@workstation:~$ awk -v s="$ver" 'BEGIN{gsub(/\./,"\\\\.",s)}$0~s{p=7}p&&/^==/{p=0}p' sample.txt
david@workstation:~$

Comment: @planetradio sorry, I didn't test just now, and forgot the most important part: output.  :D now I updated the line, and tested here. try with it again please.

Comment: it is worked!.wonderful!.but i found i only have 10 reputation.i just do not know how to send this 10 to you..   if you know,please just let me know. THANKS A LOT for your help!

Comment: @planetradio you don't give your reps to me. you can mark the answer as accepted. under the up/downvote number, there should be a tick. if you cannot find it, it's fine too. Important is your problem gets solved.

Comment: i find it. the tick now becomes green.

Comment: when i click the up array, it shows ¨ Vote up requires 15 reputation
¨  But i only have 10 reputation. when i accmulate 15 reputation,i will try to send it to you.regards!

Comment: @Kent you could remove the next and print with a bit of rearranging `awk -v s="$ver" 'BEGIN{gsub(/\./,"[.]",s)}p&&/^==/{p=0}$0~s{p=7}p'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file format will be exactly similar to shown above in problem i.e. you need only next line of your input then this can be done using simple grep command,

```
[root@giam06 home]# grep -A 2 "v2.0.2" file.txt
==2012-01-02 v2.0.2

some information about B..
[root@giam06 home]#
```

If you know next no of lines in advance then you can vary them using -A (no of lines) else AWK script is required.

Comment: what if "some information about X" contains unknown lines of text?

Comment: see updated answer. Mentioned assumption as it was not mentioned in problem.

Comment: @Nachiket, still thanks for your kindness.Thank you!